# Query in Touchpose example in github in iOS

Tags: ios, static-libraries

I have downloaded Touchpose demo from Github. Below is the link of it.

https://github.com/toddreed/Touchpose

I want to implement this in static library.

I have added QTouchposeApplication.h and QTouchposeApplication.m file in my library.

As written below in appdelegate.m file to show multitouch.

```
QTouchposeApplication *touchposeApplication = (QTouchposeApplication *)application;
touchposeApplication.alwaysShowTouches = YES;
```

Likewise, I don't understand, how should I write this in static library.

Please could someone guide me

Thanks in advance.